# Graph Nodes with different types of data

Tags: java, data-structures, graph-theory, instanceof

My problem resolves around the nodes of a graph which can contains different types of data, **A** **B** and **C**. I need to access this data while going through path of the graph.

My current idea was to make an interface **NodeData** which class **A** **B** and **C** will implement. A node will contain a **NodeData** and I'll be able to know which kind of data it is with `instanceof`.

Unfortunately, **A** **B** and **C** does not share any information and thus, **NodeData** will be an empty interface. I also think that using `instanceof` is not a great idea. But I've yet to find a better one.

Is this fine or there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Consider a visitor pattern

Comment: Adding to what WorldSEnder said, instead of having a common interface for the NodeData, consider having the Nodes be subclasses of a common Node class depending on whether they contain A, B , C

Comment: A visitor pattern does seems to fit my need, thanks.
About nodes subclasses, I'd like to separate the graph topology and the data, thus the NodeData interface, but it does not seem to be a good idea.